# Scribe (simple OAuth Java lib) and reverse auth token

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, scribe

I would like to use scribe for reverse auth token.

reverse auth token is for iPhone, however the first step of retrieving the request token I would like to do in the BE so I don't need to store the secret in the iPhone file.

According to the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) I am supposed to send a parameter called `x_auth_mode reverse_auth` and get the full response in order to make a second call.

If I am using:

```
   OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                                  .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                                  .apiKey("your_api_key")
                                  .apiSecret("your_api_secret")
                                  .build();
```

How can I send the reverse auth token as well?